# cannot open file 'glew_static_vs2010.lib' and pragma comment

Tags: c++, static-linking, cl

I'm trying to get started with a book about modern OpenGL. In the book, I need to link against some libs (i.e. `freeglut` `glew32` `vermilion32`). I've downloaded the source code for glew and generated the lib. There is no problem with linking the libs I've generated but it seems the author uses `pragma comment` and it causes some linking errors.

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'glew_static_vs2010.lib'
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\cl.EXE"' : return code '0x2'
```

In one of headers files (i.e. `vgl.h`) used in the code, there are these lines

```
#ifndef __VGL_H__
#define __VGL_H__

// #define USE_GL3W

#ifdef USE_GL3W

#include <GL3/gl3.h>
#include <GL3/gl3w.h>

#else

#define GLEW_STATIC

#include <GL/glew.h>

#ifdef _MSC_VER
#  ifdef _DEBUG
#    if (_MSC_VER >= 1600)
#      pragma comment (lib, "glew_static_vs2010_d.lib")
#    else
#      pragma comment (lib, "glew_static_d.lib")
#    endif
#  else
#    if (_MSC_VER >= 1600)
#      pragma comment (lib, "glew_static_vs2010.lib")
#    else
#      pragma comment (lib, "glew_static.lib")
#    endif
#  endif
#endif

#endif

#define FREEGLUT_STATIC

#include <GL/freeglut.h>

#ifdef _MSC_VER
#  ifdef _DEBUG
#    if (_MSC_VER >= 1600)
#      pragma comment (lib, "freeglut_static_vs2010_d.lib")
#    else
#      pragma comment (lib, "freeglut_static_d.lib")
#    endif
#  else
#    if (_MSC_VER >= 1600)
#      pragma comment (lib, "freeglut_static_vs2010.lib")
#    else
#      pragma comment (lib, "freeglut_static.lib")
#    endif
#  endif
#endif

#define BUFFER_OFFSET(x)  ((const void*) (x))

#endif /* __VGL_H__ */
```

I don't know why the author is following this approach. How can I overcome this problem? This is my Makefile

```
CC = cl
CFLAGS = /EHsc /c
INCLUDES = \
    /I D:\CPP_Projects\CommandPrompt\ModernOpenGL\Books\Opengl_Programming_Guide_8th\oglpg_8th_edition\include

LIBS = \
    /LIBPATH:D:\CPP_Projects\CommandPrompt\ModernOpenGL\Books\Opengl_Programming_Guide_8th\oglpg_8th_edition\lib \
    freeglut_staticd.lib glew32sd.lib vermilion32_d.lib

all: project    

project: triangles.obj LoadShaders.obj 
    $(CC) /EHsc /Fetest.exe triangles.obj LoadShaders.obj \
          /link  $(LIBS) 

triangles.obj: triangles.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) triangles.cpp $(INCLUDES)

LoadShaders.obj: LoadShaders.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) LoadShaders.cpp $(INCLUDES)

clean:
    del *.exe *.obj
```

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft compiler allows to use `#pragma comment (lib, "libraryname.lib")` to specify libraries that should be used by linker instead of passing them to linker on command line. Since you build your own libraries perhaps you should comment out these entire blocks for auto-linking from `vgl.h` (or even delete them):

```
#ifndef __VGL_H__
#define __VGL_H__

  // #define USE_GL3W

#ifdef USE_GL3W

#include <GL3/gl3.h>
#include <GL3/gl3w.h>

#else

#define GLEW_STATIC

#include <GL/glew.h>

// #ifdef _MSC_VER
// #  ifdef _DEBUG
// #    if (_MSC_VER >= 1600)
// #      pragma comment (lib, "glew_static_vs2010_d.lib")
// #    else
// #      pragma comment (lib, "glew_static_d.lib")
// #    endif
// #  else
// #    if (_MSC_VER >= 1600)
// #      pragma comment (lib, "glew_static_vs2010.lib")
// #    else
// #      pragma comment (lib, "glew_static.lib")
// #    endif
// #  endif
// #endif

#endif

#define FREEGLUT_STATIC

#include <GL/freeglut.h>

// #ifdef _MSC_VER
// #  ifdef _DEBUG
// #    if (_MSC_VER >= 1600)
// #      pragma comment (lib, "freeglut_static_vs2010_d.lib")
// #    else
// #      pragma comment (lib, "freeglut_static_d.lib")
// #    endif
// #  else
// #    if (_MSC_VER >= 1600)
// #      pragma comment (lib, "freeglut_static_vs2010.lib")
// #    else
// #      pragma comment (lib, "freeglut_static.lib")
// #    endif
// #  endif
// #endif

#define BUFFER_OFFSET(x)  ((const void*) (x))

#endif /* __VGL_H__ */
```

Comment: It still throws this error `LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'glew_static_vs2010.lib'`